# Swift strange '==' behavior with Dictionary

Tags: swift, swift2

In Swift 2.1, following code can be compiled.

```
let a = [1: [1]]
a == [1: [1]]
```

However, following code cannot be compiled.

```
let a = [1: [1]]
let b = [1: [1]]
a == b // => binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[Int : Array<Int>]' operands
```

**How understand this behavior?**

Comment: Using binary operator to compare to Dictionaries is not valid. You should be using isEqualToDictionary. Please refer to Apples documentation [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: @PK20: It is not that simple. There *is* a `==` operator for dictionaries (declared as `public func ==<Key : Equatable, Value : Equatable>(lhs: [Key : Value], rhs: [Key : Value]) -> Bool`), and your link refers to NSDictionary, not  Swift Dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `==` operator comparing two Swift dictionaries, however it
requires that the value type is `Equatable`:

```
public func ==<Key : Equatable, Value : Equatable>(lhs: [Key : Value], rhs: [Key : Value]) -> Bool
```

The problem is that even for equatable types `T`,  `Array<T>` *does not conform* to the `Equatable` protocol. See for example
[Why can't I make Array conform to Equatable?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7172) for a discussion
in the Apple developer forum.

That explains why

```
let a = [1: [1]]
let b = [1: [1]]
a == b // => binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[Int : Array<Int>]' operands
```

does not compile. In your first example

```
let a = [1: [1]]
a == [1: [1]]
```

the compiler is so smart to take the literal array `[1]` as an
`NSArray` literal, using

```
extension NSArray : ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    /// Create an instance initialized with `elements`.
    required public convenience init(arrayLiteral elements: AnyObject...)
}
```

And this compiles because all classes inheriting from
`NSObject` conform to `Equatable`.

Here is a simpler example demonstrating the same issue:

```
func foo<T : Equatable>(x : T) {
    print(x.dynamicType)
}

let ar = [1, 2, 3]
// This does not compile:
foo(ar) // error: cannot invoke 'foo' with an argument list of type '([Int])'

foo([1, 2, 3]) // Output: __NSArrayI
```

As one can see, the *literal* array is converted to some subclass of the
`NSArray` class cluster when passed to a function expecting an `Equatable` argument.

Note also that if you only import Swift, but not Foundation (or UIKit, ...) then neither

```
foo([1, 2, 3])
```

nor your first example compiles.

Comment: "For some reason" - the reason is simple - literals are always converted to a type that matches the expression. If the expression `x == y` requires `Equatable` and `y` is a literal then `NSArray` will be selected over `Array`. A simpler example would be `let x = 20.0; let y = 20` and then `x == y` vs `x == 20`.

Comment: @Sulthan: Good point. You are right, `20` can be both a integer literal and a floating point literal. Still it seems to be a bit inconsistent, because e.g. when passed to `func bar(x : AnyObject)`, *any* array (literal or not) is converted to NSObject if possible.

Comment: True, sometimes the compiler just tries too hard to convert types but that's only to be expected otherwise the compatibility with Obj-C APIs wouldn't be so simple. I agree that it's inconsistent but I see the reasons behind it.