# What's going on with this generic function?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

*Sorry for the generic title, it's hard to describe the problem without examples.*

Suppose I define the following generic function that is constrained to `Equatable` types:

```
func test<T: Equatable>(expect expected: T, run: () -> T) {
    let value = run()
    if value == expected {
        print("OK")
    } else {
        print("Expected: \(expected), Actual: \(value)")
    }
}
```

Here's an example of using said function:

```
test(expect: 100) { 10 * 10 } // prints "OK"
test(expect: 1000) { 10 * 10 } // prints "Expected: 1000, Actual: 100"
```

And, of course, I can store the value instead of using literals:

```
let e = 100
test(expect: e) { e } // prints "OK"
```

So far so good, everything works as expected (no pun intended).

Now let's try this with an array:

```
test(expect: [1, 2]) { [1, 2] } // prints "OK"
```

Once again, things work out.

But now we try this:

```
let a = [1, 2]
test(expect: a) { a } // error: cannot convert value of type '() -> [Int]' to expected argument type '() -> _'
```

So the question I have been building up to is: **Why doesn't this work?**

Playground correctly infers the type of `a` to be `[Int]`, so where does the expectation of `() -> _` come from?

Trying a bunch of variations of the last example:

```
test(expect: a) { return a }
test(expect: a) { return a as [Int] }
test(expect: a as [Int]) { return a as [Int] }
test(expect: [1, 2]) { a }
test(expect: [1, 2] as [Int]) { a }
```

They all result in the same problem. For some reason, Swift seems to think the function expects `() -> _`.

So maybe it's just because arrays aren't `Equatable`, but this works:

```
let a = [1, 2]
[1, 2] == [1, 2]
a == a
```

I thought I understood generics pretty well, and I'm completely stumped by this. Is this a bug in Swift or a bug in my definition of `test()`? Can the goal even be accomplished?

## The Solution

Thanks to @Sulthan's answer below, I was able to write another version of this function to handle the array case (and any `SequenceType` for that matter):

```
public func test<T: SequenceType where T.Generator.Element: Equatable>(expect expected: T, run: () -> T) {
    let result = run()
    // Note: zip() will stop at the shorter array, so this implementation isn't correct, don't use it (it will incorrectly end up saying [1] == [1,2]). This code is just here to demonstrate the function's generic constraint.
    let eq = zip(expected, result).filter(!=).isEmpty
    if eq {
        print("OK")
    } else {
        print("Expected: \(expected), Actual: \(result)")
    }
}

let a: [Int] = [1, 2]
test(expect: [1,2]) { a } // prints "OK"
test(expect: [1,3]) { a } // prints "Expected: [1, 3], Actual: [1, 2]"
```

Comment: The answer is the same as for http://stackoverflow.com/a/33732669/669586 but I am not sure whether I should close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @Sulthan It's definitely the same question at its root, but the fact that doing this through a function obfuscates the problem a bit I think makes it worthy to stand on its own. Plus, part of the question was how to make this work, which the edit to the question also addresses.

Comment: As a side note about my "solution" above. It's probably a bad idea to constrain the implementation of `test()` to a `SequenceType` because it's valid to have infinite sequences, so you don't want to try to iterate over all of them. `CollectionType` would be more appropriate.

Comment: what is the advantage of using generic function over simple == operator? i don't see any ... both returns Bool value and your function still using == operator internally

Comment: @user3441734 It's good practice to distill your code in questions to the minimal demonstrable example, which often results the example being contrived. In this case my actual implementation of this function actually ran the passed-in closure multiple times, timed each run, took the average, compared the result to the expected value and did some logging in the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays don't automatically conform to `Equatable`, even if their values are `Equatable`. However, when you use an array literal directly, the compiler tries to match the type and converts the array to an `NSArray` which does conform to `Equatable`.

Comment: This is it! Wow, this has been bugging me for some time! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, playing around with this some more.. Are you sure this is converting it to an NSArray? If I remove `import Foundation` I can no longer use NSArray, but `[1,2,3] == [1,2,3]` still works so something else must be going on.

Comment: @vopilif There is `==` defined for Arrays with `Element: Equatable`. It doesn't mean that Array implements `Equatable`.